# Android Soap Request return error

Tags: android, soap, android-ksoap2, http-error

I have this structure. It is a simple structure with a list of items.

```
<soap:Body>
<SendPositions xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <username>string</username>
  <password>string</password>
  <loc>
    <Pos>
      <Lat>double</Lat>
      <Lon>double</Lon>
      <ts>dateTime</ts>         
    </Pos>
    <Pos>
      <Lat>double</Lat>
      <Lon>double</Lon>
      <ts>dateTime</ts>
    </Pos>
  </loc>
</SendPositions>
```

I try sending request but I receive error all the time.

```
SoapObject Request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);      
            Request.addProperty("username", zG.getID());
            Request.addProperty("password", zG.getPIN());

            SoapObject locations = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "loc");                                                                
            for (Pos pozycja : zG.getListPositions())
            {
                SoapObject pos = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "Pos");       
                pos.addProperty("Lat", pozycja.getLat() + "");
                pos.addProperty("Lon", pozycja.getLon() + "");
                pos.addProperty("ts", pozycja.getDate()); // datetime yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS

                locations.addSoapObject(pos);                                       
            }
            Request.addSoapObject(locations);
            Log.i("Request", Request.toString());
```

I still thinking the problem is serialization data. So I use this code:

```
MarshalDouble md = new MarshalDouble();
md.register(soapEnvelope);
```

My log (last line in up code)

```
SendPositions{username=50000000; password=11111111111; loc{Pos{Lat=52.0; Lon=20.0; ts=2013-08-08 23:45:39.378; }Pos{Lat=52.0; Lon=20.0; ts=2013-08-08 23:46:04.416; }}}
```

My error is:

```
HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 500 - HTTP request failed, HTTP status: 500
```

I can't change settings server, unfortunately...
Do you have any idea what do I wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to send your request from SoapUI?

Comment: No because I don't know how :/